# Window XP start script before service

Tags: windows, windows-xp, script, boot, services

PC with Windows XP prof. controls small production line. On Windows start-up I want to backup production data (created last day) before system starts particular service and application. How to start backup script? Alternatively, script can be ivoked on system shutdown (just after application close).

mirek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set it as a logoff script in group policy. Open GPEdit.msc and add the script you want to run in there.
Should be in Computer configuration -> Windows Settings -> Scripts (startup / Shutdown)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Joe Taylor.

logoff script in group policy works as desired.

My test script contains commands:

```
net stop <service name> >> logfile    (stop service)
tasklist                >> logfile    (show whether application processes still exist)
copy ....               >> logfile    (do backup)
```

mirek